# Hand in contact with laptop causes oscilloscope power spike

Tags: oscilloscope, wifi

I recently placed my MacBook Pro next to an oscilloscope with a 2.4GHz monopole antenna.

Whenever I placed my hand on the metal casing of the laptop, this results in a large power spike. Why is this? I don't understand the principles behind this occurring.

These spikes do not occur when I touched the plastic keypads.

However, these spikes DO occur (with lower amplitude) when I touch the cords of my headphones (connected to the laptop).

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like a power spike.  That looks more like a high frequency sugnal of some kind.  Maybe the CPU clock, maybe the wifi, maybe something else entirely.  A spike is just that - a single, strong deflection that looks like a spike (look up spike, it is a kind of a nail.)

Comment: You start acting like antenna emitting waves on the target frequencies. When touching isolated headphone cords their signal causes capacitive effect and you also start acting like antenna (mind your environment - clothes you wear, floor, other devices around).

Comment: You are running your scope so severely *undersampled* it is very hard to tell what you are actually looking at.  It's unlikely to be wifi, but you could easily test by disabling wifi, BLE, etc in settings...

Answer (score -1):

Most likely what you see is the laptop's WiFi radio intensifies its transmission power because you blocked one of its WiFi antennas, the receiving end. The device thinks that it gets too far away from the WiFi router/access point, and automatically increases its transmitted power. The emitted power can be substantial, 0.5 W, and up to 2 W if the device has a broadband LTE modem. This is what all cell phones do.

ADDITION: Remember iPhone 4 antenna fiasco, anyone?

Comment: This does not explain the power increase when I hold the headphone cable connected to my laptop. Doing that does not block any antennas.

Comment: @user2562609, yes it does explain. A laptop is a complicated 3-dimensional electrical structure, and the headphone cable is just another part of it. Attaching extra capacitance to the system's ground does change overall antenna properties. See also the Anonymous comment above.